# Mobile Device not displaying in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sony

I am using Sony Xperia C mobile to debug the android application.

When i connect the phone to laptop via USB then eclipse not detect my phone. My Laptop configuration is 64 bit Operating System, Windows 8.1. but if I use it with 32 bit Operating system with Windows 7 then eclipse detects my phone.

Any help so that My eclipse will detect my device.

I tried different methods like windows update, install sony Companion but unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: [Install correct drivers](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/), and make sure you have enabled developer debugging options.

Comment: The link you provided does not have driver for Xperia C and if i install PC Companion then it shows no phone or tablet are connected

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Device manager tool? Does it list your phone? Or does it list the phone as something else?

Also try to update the driver from device manager, just right click on the device, click properties and then update driver and use Google's Android USB driver, which works correctly with most phones.
If your phone is not being listed in device manager it could be an issue with the OS or the USB port.s

Comment: My phone is listed in the device manager. It displays in the other devices list with yellow mark

Comment: That is a good start, use this link for further troubleshooting http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/f/yellowdm.htm

Comment: The link you provide means that drivers is not installed properly. But how update my driver. If i update from web it shows not found

Comment: Did you check the error code? http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/f/device-status.htm and then cross-check it with the known error codes? http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/tp/device_manager_error_codes.htm

Comment: it displays the error code 28. It means driver is not installed. Driver is not available for xperia c in sony website

Comment: If you are still having this problem, please install the Sony PC Suite, which will install all missing drivers

Comment: I installed Sony PC Suite. But my device will not connected with PC Suite. Its shows no device connected.